# Is using static factories a valid pattern for dependency injection?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm creating an internal framework, and at one point I would like to provide a good extensibility, supporting kind of dependecy injection.

Here is a simplified example of my filtering module in .NET/C#. Imagine there is a filter processor component, which takes a `List` of objects, each representing a filter condition. Then its task is "translate" these to Expressions and apply it to any `IQueryable`. There are trivial fitler types, for example a ColumnFilter, which refers to a fieldname, an operator, and some operands. However, I would like to provide a way to consumers to extend the filter processing mechanism with custom filter conditions. So I introduce an interface:

```
public interface IFilterProcessor {
  Expression Process(FilterContext filter);
}
```

where `FilterContext` holds information like the currently processed filter, the root ParameterExpression, the Type of the root `IQueryable`, etc., not important for this example.

Then at some point one could define a new filter condition, and provide a corresponding `IFilterProcessor` to it, and implement the translation of the condition there.

And here comes my idea, I would provice the extensibility point as staticly registerable factories, something like this:

```
public class FilterProcessor {

  public static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<IFilterProcessor>> ProcessorFactories = new ... 
    {
       {typeof(ColumnFilter), () => new ColumnFilterProcessor() }
    };

  ...
  public Expression Process(object filterCondition) {
    if (filterCondition == null) return null;
    var factory = ProcessorFactories.GetValueOfDefault(filterCondition.GetType()); // my custom Dictionary extension to avoid exceptions and return null if no key found
    if (factory == null) return null;
    using (var processor = factory()) {
      return processor.Process(filterCondition);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Then at the entry point of the application I can "register" my custom filter condition processors like this:

```
FilterProcess.ProcessorFactories[typeof(MyCustomCondition)] = () => ... get from Ninject for example ...;
```

The idea behind using this pattern is that the core framework does not have to know anything about the extensions, similar to some "plugin" system.

Note that this is farly simplified and lot of things are omitted for clarity. In reality for example my filters can be grouped, nested, etc., whole lot complex.

And now my question:
I've been reading for a long time about design patterns, especially DI, but haven't found any example similar to this one. Is this a valid, and globally accepted pattern? If there is any, could anyone point out any contras about it? Finally, if this is a valid pattern, does it have a name?

Comment: Shouldn't it be public class FilterProcessor : IFilterProcessor ?

Comment: @JimCrandall no, this is intentional. The FilterProcessor is a main class to process filters, and "accepts" several processor pugin which it uses during processing. I agree though that the name is misleading and nto the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're asking and not telling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle) by setting the processors using the property.

I think you can achieve the same outcome in a more 'classic' DI way: Make your `FilterProcessor` dependent on an enumeration of `IFilterProcessor` and then let the IoC framework do the resolution and injection for you by registering `IFilterProcessors` by convention.

Comment: Yes that's true, however I wanted to indicate to the consumer that this behaviour is an optional extending of the framework. If I put anything as constructor argument (even if I add a default constructor) it looks like it's a "hard" dependency. Another thing is that without the Dicationary implementation I would need to add a function to the interface, for example bool CanProcess(object filterCondtion). That's a good option as well. Another issue is that then I'd need to inject the FilterProcessor itself as well, which I planned to keep a simple and sealed service class, reachable from anywher

Comment: Ah, yes. I see. The optional nature suggests that the property is more suitable than a constructor. I assume that Ninject can do property injection. In relation to the original question though, which part are you referring to when you ask if it's an accepted pattern? The property injection part?

Comment: Hm.. I think I referred rather to "staticness". I've noticed a trend nowadays that static stuff is bad most of the times, so I'm alwazs thinking (probably tobb much) when I choose a pattern with using statics.

Comment: I would prefer staticness over property injection, because if I use property injection I have to rely on creating all Filterprocessor instances via IoC container. So if the framework somewhere insde creates naviely a FilterProcessor with default constructor, my extension logic won't be used there. Using staticly registered Factories I can ensure that the injected "plugins" will be used whenever a FilterProcessor is created iwthin the entire application.